# Google Apps Script function does not execute

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following function for importing data from an API. It triggers daily. Some days it runs, some it doesn't (Execution starts then it just shows 'loading' then execution times out at 6 minutes).

I copied this same function to another spreadsheet and it executes without errors. The problem seems to be with the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has a bunch of other sheets that have many formulas calculating based on the imported data.

Here's the function:

```
function loadsImport() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Loads');

  // Get the nr of rows with data in Col A
  let colARange = sheet.getRange("A2:A");
  let lastRowInColA = colARange.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  console.log("Col A has this many rows: ", lastRowInColA);

  // Get the data range where data should be imported (starting with row 2 until col 24)
  let dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRowInColA, 24);

  // Clear the data before importing
  dataRange.clear();
  console.log("dataRange has been cleared.");

  let today = new Date();
  let numDays = 30;
  today.setDate(today.getDate()-numDays);
  let since = String(today.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  today.setDate(today.getDate()+30);
  let until = String(today.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  console.log("Since: " + since + ", Until: " + until);
  
  let url = 'https://api.url' + '?Since=' + since + '&Until=' + until;
  debugger;
  const fetchOptions = {
       'headers': {
           'Authorization': 'Basic XYZ',
           'CompanyCode': 'HN0001',
           'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
           'Accept': 'application/json',
       },
  }

  var jsondataAlvys = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  var objectAlvys = JSON.parse(jsondataAlvys.getContentText());

  console.log("objectAlvys length: ", objectAlvys.length);

  var loadsArray = [];

  // Set header row
  loadsArray.push([["Load"], ["SalesAgent"], ["OwnerOperator"], ["Customer"], ["Equipment"], ["PickDate"], ["DropDate"], ["PaidLoadedMiles"], ["LoadedMiles"], ["PickCity"], ["PickState"], ["DropCity"], ["DropState"], ["LoadStatus"], ["BillableAmount"], ["EmptyMiles"], ["PaidEmptyMiles"], ["CustomerAccesorial"], ["Dispatcher"], ["Driver1"], ["Truck"], ["DateCreated"], ["NonRevenueAccesorial"], ["LastUpdated"]]);

  objectAlvys.forEach(load => {
    loadsArray.push([
      [load.Load], 
      [load.SalesAgent], 
      [load.OwnerOperator], 
      [load.Customer], 
      [load.Equipment], 
      [load.PickDate],
      [load.DropDate], 
      [load.PaidLoadedMiles], 
      [load.LoadedMiles], 
      [load.PickCity],
      [load.PickState],
      [load.DropCity],
      [load.DropState],
      [load.LoadStatus],
      [load.BillableAmount],
      [load.EmptyMiles],
      [load.PaidEmptyMiles],
      [load.CustomerAccesorial],
      [load.Dispatcher],
      [load.Driver1],
      [load.Truck],
      [load.DateCreated],
      [load.NonRevenueAccesorial],
      [load.LastUpdated]
      ]);
  });

  console.log("loadsArray length: ", loadsArray.length);

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, loadsArray.length, 24).setValues(loadsArray);

}
```

I assume the problem has to do with the formulas triggering calculation, which blocks the script from executing. But I'm not sure. Or there are some spreadsheet limits that I'm unaware of.

Comment: You should use the debugger to narrow the focus and help us determine where the problem is.  You should avoid range like `"A2:A"` instead use `"A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()"`

Comment: I am unable to use debugger, as the script does not execute at all. After "Execution started" it just shows 'loading' for 6 minutes, then Execution time ran out.

Comment: Well then you may have to resort to debugging without the debugger using Logger.log and console.log.

Comment: So the script seems to be freezing on .getSheetByName("Import").